# Rails form.object.attribute cannot be accessed inside nested_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, model, form-helpers

I am trying to access the existing parent attribute inside a nested_form_fields each loop. I am able to access the associated "products" attributes, but not the "sales_order_items" attributes. The error generated is: undefined method `service_name' for nil:NilClass.

```
<%= form.nested_fields_for :delivery_items, wrapper_tag: :tr do |ff| %>
  <td class="col-md-1">                                           
    <div class="input-product_name-div">   
        <% if ff.object.product.present? %>
          <%= ff.object.product.name %>
        <%else%>
          <%= ff.object.sales_order_item.service_name %> #this line fails
        <%end%>
    </div>
  </td> 
<% end %>
```

As you can see in my Models below, they are both associated the same way.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales_order_items 
    has_many :delivery_items
end

class SalesOrderItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :sales_order,  optional: true
    belongs_to :product,  optional: true    
    has_many :delivery_items
end
```

Here's my DeliveryItem model:

```
class DeliveryItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product,  optional: true
    belongs_to :sales_order_item,  optional: true
end
```

I am sure the item has a service name. In fact, if I use rails console, I can access it via `DeliveryItem.last.sales_order_item.service_name`

Comment: show the controller code which is rendering this form view - mainly interested in how you are getting the objects

Comment: @kiddorails - this is the only line in my edit controller `@delivery = Delivery.find(params[:id])`. Then delivery_items belongs to delivery that's why I can access it in this edit.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the form header, I changed it to this and all the nested_form.object.parent.attributes can finally be found:

```
<%= form.fields_for :delivery_items do |ff| %>
```

The issue seems to come from using the `nested_form_fields` gem. I've yet to figure out how to solve this issue without scrapping the gem, but at least my last resort would be to simply use `fields_for`. I want to use the gem because it already includes adding and removing rows via link_to and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= ff.object.sales_order_item.service_name if object.sales_order_item.present?%>
```

or for ruby version greater then `2.3.1`

```
<%= ff.object.sales_order_item&.service_name%>
```

Comment: The object is present in the database but this loop cannot detect it. if I do ff.object.sales_order_item_id, it outputs the id value, but if i do ff.object.sales_order_item.any_attribute, it fails. I tried your solution and it just just ignores the attribute because it cannot locate the object. I need the loop to recognize the parent object.

Comment: `belongs_to :sales_order_item,  optional: true` because of this line it may be some of your record has not `sales_order_item_id` and while you are doing looping for that `nil`  `sales_order_item_id` its giving error.
i would suggest you to check if any record has `nil` for `sales_order_item_id` ?

Comment: All `delivery_items` have `sales_order_item_id`, It's part of the design even in create method. My database currently has two entries only and both have `sales_order_item_id`. If i change the line to `ff.object.sales_order_item_id` all rows will output a value.

Comment: hmm if you are getting `object.sales_order_item_id` then you can do manually like this `<%=SalesOrderItem.find(ff.object.sales_order_item_id).service_name%>` for now.

Comment: I actually tried doing that too, but it errors `Couldn't find SalesOrderItem without an ID`, I tried doing `SalesOrderItem.find(ff.object.sales_order_item_id.to_i).servic‌​e_name`, but then it would default to a `0` value. If I hardcode the integer `SalesOrderItem.find(2).servic‌​e_name` it works. None of this makes sense.

Comment: thats exactly i m saying that you are missing `sales_order_item_id` in some of your record , use `binding.pry` or `debugger` and check which record has `nil` value of `sales_order_item_id` . because of that `nil`  this error `Couldn't find SalesOrderItem without an ID` is showing and `ff.object.sales_order_item_id.to_i` means `nil.to_i` which results into `0`.

Comment: Yes, but I already checked, all sales_order_item_id have values in my database. There is no nil values. I can even do the same code in rails console and it will generate an array of sales_order_item_id without nil values. I already did binding.pry and it displays all sales_order_item_id with no problem but I cannot try nested_fields_for in the rails console, so I cannot check

Comment: hmmm i m not saying to check all record use binding.pry just above this line `<%= ff.object.sales_order_item.service_name %>` and check each record one at a time.

Comment: I checked it and all records have a value to that field. I have even tried doing this `<% @int = ff.object.sales_order_item_id %>` then `<%= @int %> which outputs the integer 2 then i tried doing this `<%= SalesOrderItem.find(@int).service_name %>` and error still shows up.